# Is it safe for passing class reference(self) to the method in struct, swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, class, struct, automatic-ref-counting

Here is the code.

```
struct Nature: NatureProtocol {
}
protocol NatureProtocol {
    func doStuff(object: Hibernate)
}
extension NatureProtocol {
    func doStuff(object: Hibernate) {
        // Do some network stuff and call the object.dontMove() in completion handler
        object.dontMove()
    }
}


protocol Hibernate {
    func dontMove()
}
class Animal: Hibernate {
    let nature = Nature().doStuff(object: self)
    func dontMove() {
        print("Remain InActive")
    }
}
```

So here, In struct I am doing some networking stuff, where I will be using the self in escaping closure.

Questions:

1) How can I achieve the same with Struct to Struct?

2) Is there any better message passing technique between class and struct in swift.

Comment: Should you use `weak`? In the first place, you shouldn't pass an object, you should pass a closure. Anyway the difference between `weak` and `strong` depends on use case and ownerships.

Comment: @Sulthan, thanks will pass the closure, instead of object.